# Running python main with arguments programmatically

Tags: python, reflection

Hello I am having a piece of code that is like this `root/main.py`

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="my prog")
    parser.add_argument('--param-1')
    parser.add_argument('--param-2')
    parser_result, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    ...(do stuff with params) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and `root/folder1/folder2/util.py`

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/../../../")
import main
...
main.main(param1, param2) //errors here for wrong arguments
```

My question is how do I trigger my main with params, there is a way to use java like reflection to trigger and read correct in main my arguments? (Ideally I need as less changes on main as possible)

Also used and worked:

```
os.system("python /root/main.py --param-1 '{param1}' --param-2'{param2}'")
```

But I prefer a solution that keeps the same context and is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a way to do it like that, but the simplest way would be to add default parameters to main:

main.py

```py
def main(param1="anything", param2="anything"):
    # do something with parameters
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

util.py

```py
import main
main.main(param1, param2)
```

Comment: unfortunately I will need to remove this code to use this `    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="seismic metadata ingestor")
    parser.add_argument('--xcom')
    parser.add_argument('--ingestion_params')`

Comment: Sorry, not my cup o' tea. Good Luck!